# How can I auto calculate a column in a table without using a view

Tags: mysql

For example, I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `total_results` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `num_results_as_expected` unsigned int(10) NOT NULL,
) ;
```

I would like to add another column to the table, without using a VIEW, to add the percent of :

```
(num_results_as_expected/total_results)*100
```

Is this possible without using a VIEW?

- Clarification. I know it's possible using a select statent, but I'd like to add this in the CREATE TABLE statement, so that the column will be available to anyone who accesses the table.
- Clarification 2: Is trigger the right way to do this? This will essentially store duplicate information in the column.

Comment: With trigger it's an optimum solution. You don't store exactly the same value. If you would calculate this value each time you run select statement it would add additional overload on your server.

Comment: Hint: do you know what "demonrmalization" term is all about? :)

Comment: @koistya, the calculated percentage will be invalid when the row is updated.

Comment: @karim79, PeterMan can also add trigger which will be fired on UPDATE statement

Comment: @koistya, true, but the performance of the application will not necessarily be better - e.g. if the frequency of performing selects is greater than the frequency of updates, my solution will have more overhead, whereas if the data is updated frequently but not fetched as frequently, yours will.

Comment: With Microsoft SQL Server you could use "calculated column" for this. But with MySQL I am afraid the only option is to use regular column + trigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a regular column + add "before insert" trigger which will updated it's value with a calculated one on each insert operation. Ex.:

```
create trigger update_result before insert on test for each row
begin set new.result = (num_results_as_expected/total_results)*100;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select (num_results_as_expected/total_results)*100 as percentage from test
```

So to get all the columns including the new one:

```
select total results, num_results_as_expected, (num_results_as_expected/total_results)*100 as percentage from test
```

This prevents you from having to store anything extra, the extra column magically appears when the data is fetched.